# What does "dissipated" mean here?

Tags: cardiology, microscopy

This is the context:

> You know cardiac muscle cells are small cells relative to skeletal muscle cells, but unlike skeletal muscle cells that are arranged in parallel and **their contraction is dissipated onto a tendon to bring about movement at a joint** , cardiac muscle cells aligned **end-to-end**.

I've googled it, but it didn't make sense

> [Dissipate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dissipate)
>
> to (cause to) gradually disappear or waste

● Can anyone change it into an easier text?

● What does **dissipated** mean?

● What does **end-to-end** mean?

● I wonder whether skeletal muscle contraction is **disappeared** onto a tendon or not.

● Is there an another scientific word for **dissipated**?

> & apparently, I think **end-to-end** here means that cardiac muscle cells  join strongly to each other, but actually this is not a specific definition, I suppose.

Source:  [Cardiac Muscle: Function & Main Parts – Histology | Lecturio](https://youtu.be/8HYfcUDR4qw?t=56s).

Comment: Have you made any attempt to understand these words with tools you would use to learn english outside of science? Dictionaries, translation tools, finding other contexts, etc? We expect some effort from askers before we answer questions here.

Comment: @Bryan Krause Yes, of course, but it didn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

> What does dissipate mean?

[It's a word from a thermodynamic context](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissipation%20of%20energy). Heat can dissipate. Doing [work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)) causes energy to be lost in the form of heat, which is called dissipation. It means **to spread out** your energy, as in, a hot object - like a cup of boiling water - dissipates heat to its environment. The cup cools while the environment gets warmer. Likewise, a concentrated force (like tension across a skeletal cell within a muscle) can spread over lengthwise to connected tendons, and the energy is transferred to the bones that move.

It's really not the most precise use of the term, but it's understandable and gets the point across. To waste or to disappear is the *colloquial* meaning of the word. To dissipate, scientifically, means **to spread out energy which was once concentrated relative to its environment**. The energy can take the form of heat or work (mechanical work, in our case).

> What does end-to-end mean?

End to end means *in series*, as in, not parallel.

Cardiac cells arrange **end-to-end**:

```
beginning -- CARDIAC CELL -- CARDIAC CELL -- CARDIAC CELL -- end
```

Skeletal cells arrange like so to form a muscle:

```
beginning ---------------- SKELETAL CELL ------------------- end
beginning ---------------- SKELETAL CELL ------------------- end
```